# PHP syntax error thrown when there doesn't seem to be a syntax error

Tags: php, eclipse

`if (function_exists('gzcompress')) die(FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND);` is giving me a

> syntax error, unexpected 'if', expecting 'function' or 'const'

I am updating this code from PHP5.3 to PHP7.4 and I can't figure out what the syntax problem is since PHP allows this.  I am using Eclipse PHP to do the conversion.

Comment: Please add neighbouring code too.. A few lines above this line..

Comment: Aside from the parse error, shouldn't there be a ! in that line somewhere? Seems to be dying if the function _does_ exist.